# How can I find My thread in System?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I am writing a servlet, which must start a thread in `init()` and correctly stop it after the server is stopped. Thread downloads a web page, parses it and stores data in MySQL database.

For stopping the thread I use servlet's `destroy()` method. In this method I set condition for ending my thread. Is this the right way of doing it?

Can I see signs of the existence of my thread somewhere in my Windows? I didn't find it in Windows Task Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows task manager only shows processes, not individual threads. In fact, JVM-managed threads fall in the category of User threads, which is a distinct category from Kernel threads (managed by the operating system).

To do what you want you will have to keep a global reference to your `Thread` object, such that it's visible across different methods. It's also preferable to make your thread spin on a flag and stop it by setting the flag, instead of using something like `Thread.stop()`. Something like this:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean flag = false;

    public void setFlag(boolean value) {
        flag = value;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(!flag) {
           // execute code
        }
    }
}
```

And stop it by calling `setFlag(true)`.

Comment: +1. Note that often `Thread.interrupt()` and family is a better choice than an _ad hoc_ volatile boolean flag since thread interruption allows easy thread shutdown even when it sits in a blocking method (with few exceptions). It also plays nicely with a number of existing standard concurrency utilities like `Executors` and `Future`s.

Comment: I did so, but forgot about volatile and without function setFlag. Flag declared as field of servlet.

Comment: Can I make flag as field of Servlet Class, but not field of ThereadTask. Because I want to declare ThreadTask in Init().

Comment: It's better to have it inside the thread, such that the thread stopping logic is not exposed outside.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't see them in windows - you see processes there, not threads. Threads are internal to the jvm process.

You can see the threads in [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) (also included in JDK/bin/jvisualvm). Just connect to your tomcat and see the threads.

The `destroy()` method is a good choice. But call `thread.interrupt()`.

A better approach would be to use [Java 5 executors framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). You create an executor, and submit a `Runnable` to it. On `destroy()` you simply call `executor.shutdown()`

Comment: Sorry. Why does destroy call interrupt, if I only set flag in this method?

Comment: because the thread should not be left running forever. In fact, tomcat will interrupt it anyway, but you'll get a warning